# Getting No such file or directory - euler (Aruba::LaunchError)

Tags: ruby, rubygems, cucumber

I'm trying to use Aruba to test a gem that uses a command line interface, following the pattern here: https://github.com/radar/guides/blob/master/gem-development.md

I'm getting this error:

```
Scenario:                             # features/prob1.feature:6
Given I run `euler prob1 10 3 5`    # aruba-0.5.3/lib/aruba/cucumber.rb:60
  No such file or directory - euler (Aruba::LaunchError)
  features/prob1.feature:7:in `Given I run `euler prob1 10 3 5`'
Then the output should contain "23" # aruba-0.5.3/lib/aruba/cucumber.rb:97
```

I'm also using Thor.

This is my file /lib/euler/cli.rb:

```
require 'thor'
require 'euler'

module Euler
  class CLI < Thor
  desc "prob1 ITEM1 ITEM2 ITEM3", "finds the sum of numbers under ITEM1 that are multiples of ITEM2 or ITEM3"
    def prob1(upper_limit, num1, num2)
      puts Euler::Prob1.new(upper_limit, num1, num2).sum
    end
  end
end
```

The file /lib/euler.rb:

```
require "euler/version"
require "euler/prob1"

module Euler
  # Your code goes here...
end
```

I have played around with changing the aruba working directory in a Before block in env.rb
without success.

My "Foodie" cucumber tests run just fine, but this gem and others that I have been working on show the same Aruba::LaunchError. As near as I can tell, the setups for Foodie and Euler appear to be the same.

Any ideas on what else I could do to fix this?

Thanks!

Edited:  here is the feature definition:

```
Feature: Prob1
  In order to solve the Euler Project Problem 1
  As a CLI
  I want 3 numbers- upper limit, and the 2 divisors

Scenario:
  When I run `euler prob1 10 3 5`
  Then the output should contain "23"
```

Comment: Please show us the step definition

Comment: And why did you use the `/lib/euler/cli.rb` lib path from root? Do you have library based on the root folder?

Comment: I chose to write this as a gem, simply to further my knowledge, hence the path /lib/euler/cli.rb.  The complete path is euler/lib/euler/cli.rb.

Comment: If you are using bunlder, with **Gemfile**, and **.gemspec**, you have to run **cucumber** with the following: `bundle exec cucumber` this allow to load your own libraried, or an other that are under development. Make sure that **Gemfile**, and **.gemspec** are correctly configured.

Answer (score 0):

I have followed the same guide. You should check if you have created `bin/euler`, and have the permission to run. Attention that there should be no file extension for script `euler`.